# How to get the IMG tag above an ID tag using XPath ancestor axes

Tags: xml, python-2.7, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have the following HTML snippet:

```
    <div class="GFNQNVHJF GFNQNVHBG" style="left: 0px;width: 15px;height: 15px;position:absolute;">
    <img border="0" style="width:15px;height:15px;background:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAAN5/ncys6TuRVdp/Iqu06B2HlVnYeBclfyKjobcGoGSk4HKvoPwnmVINwFwRD+H6B4NE7N+RXtpkBFdyGau6AGdII151d0bqmvr2fD63SgE6eCNSMbUNH5Ob+qO4agvwvKOjWBGu6DNCEM6dxFdMABbZ+dVwHX/CGnoiuUaM35ZZ3q+ZVdL0HOBhpwhORoA9o4E4i/5pV3+JOsObu6Rx7o1+UMww8AANkFdufA16fyAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC) no-repeat 0px 0px;" src="http://test1:8080/clearcore/ClearCore/clear.cache.gif" onload="this.__gwtLastUnhandledEvent="load";"/>
</div>
<div class="GFNQNVHLF GFNQNVHNF">
<div style="padding-left: 22px;position:relative;zoom:1;">
<div style="left:0px;margin-top:-8px;position:absolute;top:50%;line-height:0px;">
    <img border="0" style="width:16px;height:16px;background:url(data:image/png;base64,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) no-repeat 0px 0px;" src="http://test1:8080/clearcore/ClearCore/clear.cache.gif" onload="this.__gwtLastUnhandledEvent="load";"/>
</div>
<div>
<div id="operations_edit_process_list_tab_groups_ct_groups_and_tasks_task_2">
<span>
    <span class=" myinlineblock" title="Matches" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;width:100%;">Matches</span>
</span>
```

There are 2 IMG tags and then the ID tag.  I am trying to locate the first IMG tag.  I would like to start from the ID tag using XPATH.

My XPath is locating both IMG tags.  I only want the first IMG tag.
My XPath is:

```
//div[@id="operations_edit_process_list_tab_groups_ct_groups_and_tasks_task_2"]/ancestor::div[4]//img
```

How do I locate the first IMG tag using ancestor as I would like to start from the ID tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to identify the same using `ancestor` only then in that case you can go ahead with following option:-

First you have to identify the div which has the first image tag, that `div` isn't the ancestor of `div` with `id = operations_edit_process_list_tab_groups_ct_groups_and_tasks_task_2`. It is the `sibling` of that particular div.

So you need to first identify the sibling using:-

```
(//div[@id="operations_edit_process_list_tab_groups_ct_groups_and_tasks_task_2"]/ancestor::div/preceding-sibling::div)[1]
```

Once the div is identified using the above xpath, you can then traverse for its child to find the `img` tag.

```
(//div[@id="operations_edit_process_list_tab_groups_ct_groups_and_tasks_task_2"]/ancestor::div/preceding-sibling::div)[1]/img
```

It will give you the first image tag.

But I would like to say that this is highly inefficient method if you only have to identify the image in case you don't need the `div` with aforesaid id.

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML is malformed.  Fix this first.   Then...

Wrap the XPath in parens `()` and append `[1]` to select the first node:

```
(xpath-that-selects-multiple-nodes)[1]
```

Also note that you can avoid using the `ancestor` axis by specifying the contained `div` directly in a predicate of the ancestor `div`:

```
(/div[div/div/div/@id='operations_edit_process_list_tab_groups_ct_groups_and_tasks_task_2']//img)[1]
```